# NSStatusItem to be always left?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, statusbar

I'm working on an app that displays certain information on the status menu, and I was wondering if there's any Cocoa API that can make my NSStatusItem always placed on the most-left, no matter when it's started or if other apps are started after it.

```
NSStatusBar *bar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
barItem = [[bar statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking you ultra-literally for a moment, what if two applications used such an API? They would fight and roll off the end of the menu bar. ☺

There is no supported way to do it, but there is [an undocumented/unsupported way to specify the “priority” of the status item when you create it](http://cocoadev.com/?NSStatusItem). Of course, use at your own risk, and be sure to do a `respondsToSelector:` check to fall back on the supported way if the unsupported way goes away.

Comment: I was quite sure that the operating system imposes "all are equal" rules when adding status bar items, but there's always an "undocumented way"..

Thanks for your answer and your help.